# Under what conditions does SQL Server encrypt tempdb?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, tempdb, transparent-data-encryption

When does tempdb get encrypted with Transparent Data Encryption?  What configuration, etc, causes tempdb to be encrypted this way?

Comment: I believe if you turn on TDE on *any* database in the instance, `tempdb` gets encrypted, too. Is that what you're getting at? The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes, Jon, that's what I'm getting at.  I'd love to find a better way to word/frame the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you encrypt the first database in the instance, `tempdb` will also be encrypted.  As per [this reference on TDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx):

> **Transparent Data Encryption and the tempdb System Database**
>
> The tempdb system database will be encrypted if any other database on
>   the instance of SQL Server is encrypted by using TDE.

This will be the case when you set [`ENCRYPTION ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) on a database.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't seem to include information about *which* certificate is used for tempdb. (E.g. if you use a separate certificate to encrypt different database catalogs.)

Comment: @Granger: While I don't know I have reason to believe the answer is "none of them".